# Download htaccess protected files using PHP and CURL

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, file

I tried to download files in a htaccess protected directory using php and curl. This is my code:

```
$username = "MyUsername";
$password = "MyPassword";
$url = "http://www.example.com/private/file.pdf";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But this code does nothing... how can I initiate the download of file.pdf?

Thank you!

Also, if I echo $output, i get this:

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.example.com/private/file.pdf [content_type] => application/pdf [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 264 [request_size] => 116 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.007898 [namelookup_time] => 0.006777 [connect_time] => 0.006858 [pretransfer_time] => 0.006922 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 27369 [speed_download] => 3465307 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 27369 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.007839 [redirect_time] => 0 )
```

Comment: What do you mean "does nothing"? What is the output and what are the errors returned in `$info`?

Comment: It do not return any error, in $info returns 200 OK, but the download do not initietes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` option that seems missing. The output you pasted is `$info` not `$output` btw. It shows the download happened, `download_content_length` is 27369.

Answer (score 6):

here is the working code, you made a mistake on the line with : `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);`

```
$username = "MyUsername";
$password = "MyPassword";
$url = "http://www.example.com/private/file.pdf";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf");
echo ($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to download a file, you should use `CURLOPT_FILE` instead of doing a `RETURNTRANSFER = true`. That'll write the downloaded data out to a file on your system directly, without flood PHP's memory space. Remember, PHP generally runs with a memory limit, and you can easily exceed it by downloading a large file.

Using `RETURNTRANSFER` is only useful if you're going to be doing in-memory processing of the transferred data, such as loading HTML into the DOM system for parsing.

Try this instead:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, "/name/of/file/to/write/to/on/your/machine");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: It is good to copy the file in the server, but I want to download the file in my pc, or in the my users pc.

Comment: In that case, just eliminate the returntransfer completely. by default curl will output whatever it downloads to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = "MyUsername";
$password = "MyPassword";
$url = "http://www.example.com/private/file.pdf";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf");
echo ($output);
```

This code works, just tried with excel, word and pdf document.

There is missing in the original code the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);`, the headers `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf");` and the echo `echo ($output);`.

Thanks for your answers, specially to chx for the CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER option!