# Files in htaccess protected folder read by PHP script in the same folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, directory, protected

I have a folder protected by .htaccess (digest authentication). I need to read outputs of some scripts located in subfolders of this folder using file_get_contents. This reading script is located in the protected folder root. It can't perform the file_get_contents function because of the folder protection.
Is there any way to allow certain PHP scripts to operate in the folder by some htaccess settings so I won't have to create some cURL based login sessions in the scripts?

Comment: when calling file_get_contents, do you pass an uri (`http://domain.com/file.php`) or a local path ( /folder/file.php) ?

Comment: I used full URL, local path seemed to do nothing

Comment: then you can probably use `http://login:password@www.domain.com/folder/file.php`

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it throws "Authorization Required" as well

Comment: To be sure, I used the URL in browser and it asks for username and password. It might be because it's digest type, I'll take a look at it closer

Comment: yeah maybe you are right :/ (don't know about digest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create rewrite rules based on useragent string. And then in your curl request you need to set a usearagent string allowed in your htaccess file.

Comment: If cURL has to be used, then it's probably easier to do that this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944410/download-htaccess-protected-files-using-php-and-curl without htaccess modification?

Comment: Yes I think so. But if you'll change the login/pwd for protected directory - you should change the access details in your scripts. So if you will have multiple instances of your PHP script, I think that useragent way will take less time for maintenance.

Comment: I have one script with cURL that is included into the others. Your solution would save this one step when I'll be changing the password, but isn't it potentially dangerous? It seems to me it's like using the Basic authentication type from security POV.

Comment: If you using some long unique token for useragent (for exmaple $%#$@#$%%^*^&%&^%$%^%^%^#%*&*^&*^#$!@##@%$) - I think that it has the same chances to be cracked as if you would use login/password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simplest way is to use cURL in the same way as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5872712/965748
and just change CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH to CURLAUTH_DIGEST and optionally remove some specific options.