# How to request a non-public PHP page using PHP?

Tags: php

To request a public-facing page, you can simply do:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://mysite.com/file.php");
```

But the file I want to request is not a publicly available page. Is there any way to request it without resorting to server configurations?

To be clear, I do not want the source code of the .php file - I want to execute the PHP in the file and get the resulting html as a string.

Comment: This might be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: On the *same* server or some other 3rd party server?

Comment: The answer depends on how the requested page is protected.

Comment: how about if($ip!='XXXXXX')exit;

Comment: @deceze The file I want to request is on the same server.

Comment: Does this file on the same server require a username and password to access the file? Is it using http basic auth, or does the page first require a login with a session (ie, require cookies?) If it requires cookies, cURL would be your best solution.

Comment: @JonathanGraef Then you don't need make any sort of protected request *at all*. You simple `include` the file. No need to expose it publicly with some sort of home baked authentication.

Comment: @deceze Including the file would merge the PHP global namespaces, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JonathanGraef Then the correct thing to do here is to properly encapsulate your code so it's modular and reusable. If that's not possible... yeah, go with some flavor of `exec`.

Comment: @decez Its for a CMS, so there's going to be a whole lot of improperly encapsulated code flying about before long, and the CMS needs to not break because of it. I've looked at the alternatives, and this seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Not quite sure why a CMS is particularly prone to accumulate bad code, but okay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call the php file with a command line call like this

```
$content = shell_exec('php /path/to/your/file.php');
```

Comment: Whatever happened to `include`?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not a public facing file, your first move is to put it in a location that public cannot access, e.g., not in your sites public folder, but a level up from there. That way, nobody will ever be able to access it, except for files residing on the same server.

Next, instead of using `file_get_contents()` to load up a url, use `exec()` to execute the php script like this

```
exec('php /path/to/file.php', $output);
print_r($output); // each line of the output is stored in the $output array
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for mroe info

Comment: in this case, I'd agree, shell_exec is probably a better option

Answer (score 0):

> But the file I want to request is not a publicly available page. Is there any way to request it without resorting to server configurations?

If it's an external file, no, there isn't a way to by-pass server configurations. Essentially by pointing `file_get_contents()` to a PHP file, you *are* telling the web server to execute it and if it was made to print a bunch of information, it will exactly do that. [CURL may be the better choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944410/download-htaccess-protected-files-using-php-and-curl) if you are trying to access .htaccess password protected files.

Comment: According to the Manual: "file_get_contents() returns the file in a string." This is not what I want - I want to execute the PHP in the file and get the result.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by making the file public, but protecting it with a password. Then the page will still be protected from the outside world, but can be requested with file_get_contents().

In the requesting page:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://mysite.com/file.php?password=h29kd8cm28x");
```

And in the (now public) page being requested:

```
if ($_GET['password'] != 'h29kd8cm28x') {
    die("Access denied!");
} else {
    // page contents here
}
```

However this seems like a clunky solution, and requires extra work to prevent hackers from learning the password.

Comment: It looks like he don't cares about. Note that the opener posted the question in the same minute as his own *low quality answer*

Comment: Generating a new password for each request fixes the problem, but the password would need to be stored somewhere, e.g. in a database, so that the page being requested knows what the current password is.

Comment: There are so many existing password protection solutions (\*cough\*HTTP\*Auth\*cough\*) and you're resorting to query parameters...? Not to mention using a proper API with mutual authentication (SSL certificates, Oauth tokens or whathaveyou)...

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep the PHP file in document root or its sub-folders. Assuming you are calling call.php from run.php:

```
// call.php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='run.php') { // Or the full path of run.php
    // Code here
}

// run.php
$html = file_get_contents("http://sitename.com/call.php");
```

If call.php should be outside the document root, shell_exec is an option, as mentioned by silly.